# Spring boot Rest api with Spring Kafka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have designed a Spring boot REST API ADD and GET method

```
    @RestController("ProductV1Controller")
    public class ProductController 
     {

         private final IProductProducer _productProducer;
         public ProductController(IProductProducer productProducer) {
        _productProducer = productProducer;}

         @PostMapping()
            void AddProduct(@Valid @RequestBody ProductViewModel product) {
                _productProducer.AddProduct(product);
            }
        
        @GetMapping()
            List<ProductViewModel> Products() {
                var test = _productProducer.GetProducts();
                return _productProducer.GetProducts();
            }
}
```

## Service layer

```
@Service

    public class ProductProducer implements IProductProducer{
        private final KafkaTemplate<String, Object> _template;
    
        public ProductProducer(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> _template) {
            this._template = _template;
        }
    
        @Override
        public List<ProductViewModel> GetProducts() {
            this._template.send(ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCTS,null);
            return List.of(new ProductViewModel("","",0,"")); --> Need to return the value from the kafka
        }
    
        @Override
        public void AddProduct(ProductViewModel product) {
            this._template.send(ProductTopicConstants.ADD_PRODUCT, product);
        }
       
    }
```

## Kafka Listener

```
 @KafkaListener(id = ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCTS, topics = ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCTS)
    public List<Product> GetProducts() {
        return _productRepository.findAll();
    }
```

In the service layer `GetProducts()` I need to return the list of the project that is coming from the `_productRepository.findAll();`

What is the best approach to do the REST API with Spring kafka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` to return a result to the rest controller.

See [ReplyingKafkaTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#replying-template).

> Version 2.1.3 introduced a subclass of KafkaTemplate to provide request/reply semantics. The class is named ReplyingKafkaTemplate and has one method (in addition to those in the superclass).

> The result is a ListenableFuture that is asynchronously populated with the result (or an exception, for a timeout). The result also has a sendFuture property, which is the result of calling KafkaTemplate.send(). You can use this future to determine the result of the send operation.

The documentation has an example.

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class So63058608Application {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So63058608Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So63058608Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, List<String>> replyTemplate;

    @GetMapping(path = "/get")
    public List<String> getThem() throws Exception {
        RequestReplyFuture<String, String, List<String>> future =
                this.replyTemplate.sendAndReceive(new ProducerRecord<>("so63058608-1", 0, null, null));
        LOG.info(future.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).getRecordMetadata().toString());
        return future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).value();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so63058608-1", topics = "so63058608-1", splitIterables = false)
    @SendTo
    public List<String> returnList(@Payload(required = false) String payload) {
        return new ArrayList<>(List.of("foo", "bar", "baz"));
    }

    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, List<String>> replyer(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf,
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, List<String>> containerFactory) {

        containerFactory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate(pf));
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, List<String>> container = replyContainer(containerFactory);
        ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, List<String>> replyer = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);
        return replyer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, List<String>> replyContainer(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, List<String>> containerFactory) {

        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, List<String>> container =
                containerFactory.createContainer("so63058608-2");
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("so63058608-2");
        container.setBatchErrorHandler(new BatchLoggingErrorHandler());
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so63058608-1").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic3() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so63058608-2").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*

spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

```
$ curl localhost:8080/get
["foo","bar","baz"]
```

**EDIT2**

And with a list of some object returned...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class So63058608Application {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So63058608Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So63058608Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, List<Foo>> replyTemplate;

    @GetMapping(path = "/get")
    public List<Foo> getThem() throws Exception {
        RequestReplyFuture<String, String, List<Foo>> future =
                this.replyTemplate.sendAndReceive(new ProducerRecord<>("so63058608-1", 0, null, null));
        LOG.info(future.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).getRecordMetadata().toString());
        List<Foo> result = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).value();
        LOG.info(result.toString());
        return result;
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so63058608-1", topics = "so63058608-1", splitIterables = false)
    @SendTo
    public List<Foo> returnList(@Payload(required = false) String payload) {
        return new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Foo("foo"), new Foo("bar"), new Foo("baz")));
    }

    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, List<Foo>> replyer(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf,
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, List<Foo>> containerFactory) {

        containerFactory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate(pf));
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, List<Foo>> container = replyContainer(containerFactory);
        ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, List<Foo>> replyer = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);
        return replyer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, List<Foo>> replyContainer(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, List<Foo>> containerFactory) {

        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, List<Foo>> container =
                containerFactory.createContainer("so63058608-2");
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("so63058608-2");
        container.setBatchErrorHandler(new BatchLoggingErrorHandler());
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so63058608-1").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic3() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so63058608-2").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    public static JavaType returnType(byte[] data, Headers headers) {
        return TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
                .constructCollectionLikeType(List.class, Foo.class);
    }

}

class Foo {

    private String bar;

    public Foo() {
    }

    public Foo(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo [bar=" + this.bar + "]";
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.type.method=com.example.demo.So63058608Application.returnType
```

```
[Foo [bar=foo], Foo [bar=bar], Foo [bar=baz]]
```

Comment: Is there any sample application with Rest API ?

Comment: No, but I added an example to my answer.

Comment: How to pass String or Object. When I tried RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> future =
                this._replyTemplate.sendAndReceive(new ProducerRecord<>(ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCT, 0, null,"uu7777uuuuuuu")); I get an exception  Failed to convert from JSON;

Comment: Don'y put code in comments; it doesn't render well; edit the question instead and include the full stack trace. And comment that you have done so, so I get a notification.

Comment: I have added a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63099836/failed-to-convert-from-jsonunexpected-character-f-code-102-expected-spac/63099892

Comment: There is also a more lightweight example on how to use the ReplyingKafkaTemplate in the spring docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#replying-template