# Mapping Types and List

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In my consumer I reply to some topic after processing the message

```
@KafkaListener(...)
@SendTo
public Message<List<Foo>> consumeOdr(ConsumerRecord<String, String> message,
        @Header(required = false, value = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key,
        @Header(required = false, value = KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC) byte[] topicReply,
        @Header(required = false, value = KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID) byte[] correlationId,
        @Header(required = false, value = KafkaHeaders.REPLY_PARTITION) byte[] partitionReply) {

    ....

    MessageBuilder<List<Foo>> builder = MessageBuilder.withPayload(fooList);
    builder
            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, key)
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, correlationId)
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, topicReply)
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.PARTITION_ID, new BigInteger(partitionReply).intValue());
    return builder.build();
}
```

The mapping conf

```
spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping: >
  fooResponse: java.util.ArrayList
```

When I inspect the produced message headers

`__TypeId__` -> `fooResponse`
`__ContentTypeId__` -> `java.lang.Object`

1. Why in the `__ContentTypeId__` Spring Kafka use `java.lang.Object`
   instead of `Foo` fully qualified class name ?
2. If I have another list of type `Bar` that I produce to some topic, how
   can I set the `spring.json.type.mapping` property correctly with `barResponse` along with the existing `fooResponse`
3. any suggestions or pattern to enhance the existing approach to consume and produce message will be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to type erasure. Use a method on the consuming side to determine the type.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#serdes-type-methods

> Starting with version 2.5, you can now configure the deserializer, via properties, to invoke a method to determine the target type. If present, this will override any of the other techniques discussed above. This can be useful if the data is published by an application that does not use the Spring serializer and you need to deserialize to different types depending on the data, or other headers. Set these properties to the method name - a fully qualified class name followed by the method name, separated by a period.

Example:

```java
public static JavaType returnType(byte[] data, Headers headers) {
    return TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
            .constructCollectionLikeType(List.class, Foo.class);
}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.type.method=com.example.demo.So63058608Application.returnType
```

Complete example in my answer to this question [Spring boot Rest api with Spring Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058608/spring-boot-rest-api-with-spring-kafka)